# Django admin: Default model display problem

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In django models, if we have
`def __unicode__(self):` then it will be used as how you want to display the model by default

Now in django admin, I want to have a custmized display field(showing this object as an url so can navigate to this object), but I can't change **unicode** method for it used for other purpose. What do I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `__unicode__` for a purpose like setting a convenience URL.

That will obscure your printed object name for any other purpose.

From which view are you trying to create a link? From the changelist view? From the change view? From a foreign key?

In general, you can simply define any method on your model (or `ModelAdmin`), that returns a full HTML link `<a href=`, set `allow_tags = True`, and refer to it in your admin fields.

```
# models method
def admin_url(self):
    return '<a href="%s">Edit Model</a>' % the_url
admin_url.allow_tags = True


# ModelAdmin method, through ForeignKey
def admin_url(self, obj):
   return '<a href="%s">Edit Model</a>' % obj.foreignkey.url
admin_url.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom method for admin class

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'active_status')

    def active_status(self, obj):
        if obj.profile.is_active:
            return """One"""
        return """Two"""

    active_status.allow_tags = True
    active_status.description = ""
```

This is just very simple example, so you can put your logic into this function
You can also return some html code

Answer (score 0):

I agree with those answers, but on my machine just not working.

I was using Python3 and Django1.8, and try to use this.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyModel: {}'.format(self.name)
```